# Updating UiTableViewCell at varying rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is how the current tableView looks like.

[image]

What I would like to do is to edit the Cell out of order. I would like for the 24 to appear in round 1 instead of round 2 where it appears and have G2 have a delayed update, so it updates the round that was played preivous before game 1, and game 3 to be 1 round behind game 2. So the updates for G1 would be as normal, each new tableViewCell creates a new round, but for game 2, the first input would be displayed in round 1 as follows while Game 1 is on round 2.

Here is my current method for how I configure the tableViewCell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSIndexPath *g2IndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row)-1 inSection:0];



    if ([p1G1ScoreArray count] > 0 && [p1G1ScoreArray count] >= indexPath.row){
        UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        NSString *label1String = [p1G1ScoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [label1 setText:label1String];
    }

    if ([p2G1ScoreArray count] > 0 && [p2G1ScoreArray count] >= indexPath.row ){
        UILabel *label2 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
        NSString *label2String = [p2G1ScoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [label2 setText:label2String];
    }


    if ([p1G2ScoreArray count] >0 && g2RowIndex >= 0 &&[p1G2ScoreArray count] >= g2IndexPath.row){
        UILabel *label3 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
        NSString *label3String = [p1G2ScoreArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)-1];
        [label3 setText:label3String ];
    }

    if ([p2G2ScoreArray count] >0 && g2RowIndex >= 0 &&[p2G2ScoreArray count] >= g2IndexPath.row){
        UILabel *label4 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
        NSString *label4String = [p2G2ScoreArray objectAtIndex:g2IndexPath.row];
        [label4 setText:label4String];
    }

    if ([p1G3ScoreArray count] >0 &&[p1G3ScoreArray count] >= indexPath.row){
        UILabel *label5 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
        NSString *label5String = [p1G3ScoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [label5 setText:label5String];
    }

    if ([p2G3ScoreArray count] >0 &&[p2G3ScoreArray count] >= indexPath.row){
        UILabel *label6 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:6];
        NSString *label6String = [p2G3ScoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [label6 setText:label6String];
    }


    UILabel *roundTrackerLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    NSString *roundTrackerLabelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Round %d", indexPath.row +1];
    [roundTrackerLabel setText:roundTrackerLabelString];


    return cell;

}
```

EDIT

Here is how data is added

```
- (IBAction)addNewRoundButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    i++;
    g2RowIndex ++;
    j = i -2;
    [p1G1ScoreArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 2+i]];
    if (g2RowIndex >= 0){
        [p1G2ScoreArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 22+i]];

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean edit cell?  You want to click on cell and edit it or just the scores that it shows.  If you just want the scores to show in different locations then it all depends on your model.  If you change it in the model and reload the table it will change.  I think your model is very complicated.  You have so many different arrays with score for each game.  There has to be a way to simplify the model and then you can easily update it.

Comment: Good question, what I mean edit is to have information appear after the user has tapped Add Round button. Each time the add round button is tapped, the score is displayed in various rows on the app.

Comment: Would you be able to post the code from the add method and where the scores are calculated.  I don't think you should have so many ifs in cellForRowAtIndexPath  Your model should have only the rounds that are added and then when you click add round you add the scores into the array and reload the tableview

Comment: just posted the edit, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your code here, I would suggest just adding each new input to the array and dont worry about the index. As for your check try this method for each array.

```
if ([p1G1ScoreArray count] > indexPath.row){
        UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        NSString *label1String = [p1G1ScoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [label1 setText:label1String];
            }
```

The indexes of each array is its count-1 since arrays work off of an offset from the first item. the = item is throwing off the check.